# Grails request parameter type conversion

Tags: grails, spring-mvc

In my Grails app, I need to bind a request parameter to a `Date` field of a command object. In order to perform the String-to-Date conversion, one needs to register an appropriate [PropertyEditor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditor.html?is-external=true) in `grails-app\conf\spring\resources.groovy`

I've added the following bean definiton:

```
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

    beans = {
        paramDateEditor(CustomDateEditor, new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy"), true) {} 
    }
```

But I'm still getting an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: "04/01/99"]
```

I think there's probably just something wrong with the way I've defined the bean, but I've no idea what?

Comment: In your SimpleDateFormat the 'mm' should be 'MM' for "Month of year". I did a quick test, and SimpleDateFormat's parse() won't throw an IllegalArgumentException with your format and input string, so that's probably not the cause of the issue, but it's noteworthy. :)

Comment: Thanks, I changed the format string in the code (and above), but the problem remains

Comment: What about using `CustomDateEditor.class` as the first argument to `paramDateEditor()`? I'm just throwing stuff at the wall here, seeing if it sticks. I'm familiar with Grails but don't have much experience binding Command objects.

Comment: That won't work. The first argument has to be the class of the bean that is being created

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The piece you are missing is registering of the new property editor.  The following worked for me when I upgraded to Grails 1.1 and had to bind dates in the MM/dd/yyyy format.

### grails-app/config/spring/resources.groovy:

```
beans = { 
    customPropertyEditorRegistrar(util.CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar) 
}
```

### src/groovy/util/CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar.groovy:

```
package util 

import java.util.Date 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat 
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor 
import org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistrar 
import org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistry 

public class CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar { 
  public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) { 
      registry.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy"), true)); 
  } 
}
```