# Grails Date Property Editor

Tags: grails, editor, properties

i'm using the jQuery UI datepicker instead of the `<g:datePicker>`, which is changing the selected date in a textbox. Now I want to save this neatly back into my database, and came across custom property editors. [click me hard to see the topic on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370240/grails-request-parameter-type-conversion)

However, adding this custom PropertyEditor didn't change anything, dates are still displayed like '2010-01-01 00:00:00.0' and if I try to save a date it crashes with `Cannot cast object '05.05.2010' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date'`.

Is there any additional magic needed, like a special naming of the textbox or something like that?

Comment: It works, but is too complicated in my opinion. I got it working with the solution above (PropertyEditor), but don't ask me what my mistake was...

Answer (score 7):

You many need to check the GrailsBinder code. However I have a possibly simpler solution. Below is some JQuery Code which finds all the g:datePicker code and renders a Grails Date Picker. It hides the original Select Boxes (so this code will **degrade** gracefully) then insert a new Textbox and the JQuery UI Datepicker. This solution also works when the user changes just the Text box without dropping down the date picker.

```
 function updateDatePicker () { 
    $("input[value='date.struct']:hidden").each(function() {
        var dateFormat = "dd/mm/yy";
        var name = $(this).attr('name');            
        var id = name.replace(".", "_").replace("[", "_").replace("]", "_") + "_input"; // Create JQuery Friendly ID

        if ($('#'+id).length == 0) {

            // Find the Select Elements
            var selectDay= $(this).nextAll("select:eq(0)").hide();
            var selectMonth = $(this).nextAll("select:eq(1)").hide();
            var selectYear = $(this).nextAll("select:eq(2)").hide();

            // Get the Values
            var dateDay= $(selectDay).val();
            var dateMonth = $(selectMonth).val();
            var dateYear = $(selectYear).val();

            // Calculate the Current Input Value
            var val = "";           
            if (dateDay != "" && dateYear != "" && dateMonth != "") { // If there is a date in the Selects then use it otherwise it's empty
                var date = new Date (dateYear, dateMonth-1, dateDay);
                val = $.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, date);
            }

            // Create element
            var template = "<input type='text' name='"+ id +"' id='"+ id +"' value='"+ val +"'/>";

            if ($(this).parent(".datePickerCalenderView").size()) {
                template = "<div id='"+ id +"'/>";
            }


            $(this).before(template);       
            var displayWidget = $('#' + id );

            displayWidget.blur(function() {         
                var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, $(this).val());

                if (date == null) {
                    $(selectDay).val("");
                    $(selectMonth).val("");
                    $(selectYear).val("");
                }
                else {
                    $(selectDay).val(date.getDate());
                    $(selectMonth).val(date.getMonth()+1);
                    $(selectYear).val(date.getFullYear());
                }
            }).keydown(function(event) {
                // Show popup on Down Arrow
                if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                    displayWidget.datepicker("show");
                }
            });

            displayWidget.datepicker({  
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: dateFormat,
                constrainInput: true,           
                showButtonPanel: true,
                showWeeks: true,
                showOn: 'button',           
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
                    if (inst == null) {
                        $(selectDay).val("");
                        $(selectMonth).val("");
                        $(selectYear).val("");
                    }
                    else {
                        $(selectDay).val(inst.selectedDay);
                        $(selectMonth).val(inst.selectedMonth+1);
                        $(selectYear).val(inst.selectedYear);
                    }
                }           
            });     
        }
    });   
}
```

Finally add this code to update the inputs when the page loads and when an AJAX call is made

```
$(document).ready (function (){ 
    updateDatePicker();

    $("#spinner").ajaxComplete (function(event, request, settings){   
        updateDatePicker();
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks very cool; is this the recommended way to implement progressive enhancement with Grails?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "progressive enhancement" but I like it because it leaves Grails as is and works well. It also degrades very well so it should work.

Comment: Progressive enhancement ~= graceful degradation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)

Comment: Thanks, I learnt something. I guess this is ONE way to implement progressive enhancement with Grails

Comment: Thanks I was looking for something like that. Still works great with Grails 2.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have a created a simple grails custom tag to use the jQuery UI datepicker. It's characteristics are as follows:

1. It creates three hidden input fields dateField_day, dateField_month, dateField_year
2. It's responsible for populating these hidden input fields when a date has been selected from the calendar.
3. Supports having multiple date fields without any conflict.

It's prerequisites are as follows:

1. You have to have jquery installed and configured properly in your app structure. That is all the js, css, and themes

The taglib code is as follows:

```
class JqueryDatePickerTagLib {
```

def jqDatePicker = {attrs, body ->
    def out = out
    def name = attrs.name
    def id = attrs.id ?: name

```
//Create date text field and supporting hidden text fields need by grails
out.println "<input type=\"text\" name=\"${name}\" id=\"${id}\" />"
out.println "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"${name}_day\" id=\"${id}_day\" />"
out.println "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"${name}_month\" id=\"${id}_month\" />"
out.println "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"${name}_year\" id=\"${id}_year\" />"

//Code to parse selected date into hidden fields required by grails
out.println "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> \$(document).ready(function(){"
out.println "\$(\"#${name}\").datepicker({"
out.println "onClose: function(dateText, inst) {"
out.println "\$(\"#${name}_month\").attr(\"value\",new Date(dateText).getMonth() +1);"
out.println "\$(\"#${name}_day\").attr(\"value\",new Date(dateText).getDate());"
out.println "\$(\"#${name}_year\").attr(\"value\",new Date(dateText).getFullYear());"
out.println "}"
out.println "});"
out.println "})</script>"
```

}
}

The gsp code is as follows:

```
<g:jqDatePicker name="orderDate"/>
```

You can find the full article at: [My Blog](http://www.dariopardo.com/grails/jquerydatepickergrailstag/)

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be that much magic.

**resources.groovy**

```
beans = {
    customPropertyEditorRegistrar(CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar)
}
```

**src/groovy/{yourpackage}/CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar.groovy**

```
class CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {
    @Override
    void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {
        // Always set the nullable to true and handle not nullable fields through constraints
        registry.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"), true));
    }
}
```