# How to pass a g:datePicker value through a remoteFunction?

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, datepicker

I tried to pass a g:datePicker value through a remoteFunction.But it return a null value.Anyone knows how to solve this problem?
My GSP page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" %>
<html>
    <g:javascript library="jQuery"/>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
        <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Select Category :</td>
                    <td><g:select name="category" 
                        from="['Crop','Location','Pest and Disease']" 
                        onchange="${remoteFunction(controller:'AG10_aggregationReport', 
                        action:'view', update:'report',
                        params:'\'filter=\'+document.getElementById(\'req_date\').value' )};"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>Date :</td>
                    <td><g:datePicker name="req_date" id="req_date" value=""/></td>
                    <td><g:submitButton name="view" value="View"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="report"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically grails expects the field names to be:

```
 ${fieldName}_year, ${fieldName}_month, ${fieldName}_day
```

with a hidden field named `${fieldName}` containing the value 'date.struct'.

It will then parse out the data for you when it encounters the `'date.struct'` on the back end. When you get the value from `req_date` you're getting `'date.struct'` which, obviously, is not a date. You can to read some workarounds here:

[Grails Date property editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662598/grails-date-property-editor/2664203#2664203)

http://www.dariopardo.com/grails/jquerydatepickergrailstag/