# Does Grails have a built-in way to bind a string to a date for a single bean property?

Tags: data-binding, grails

I know that it's possible to register a custom property editor, as [demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370240/grails-request-parameter-type-conversion/1370709#1370709). It is my understanding that this will cause all properties for the registered type to be bound using that custom editor.

<sub>(Perhaps that's a misunderstanding on my part? If so, enlighten me!)</sub>

However, what if I only want to register a custom editor for a single property on a given domain?

Example:

```
class MyCommand {
    Date foo // bind this using a custom format, e.g. 'yyyy-MM-dd'
    Date bar // bind this using the normal 'struct' date picker fields
}

class MyController {
    def myAction = { MyCommand command ->
        // params has [foo: '2011-01-01', bar: 'struct', ...]
        // which get bound to command as above
    }
}
```

**Does Grails have a built-in way to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that it's possible to register a custom property editor, as demonstrated here. It is my understanding that this will cause all properties for the registered type to be bound using that custom editor.

AFAIK, this is correct

> However, what if I only want to register a custom editor for a single property on a given domain?

If you're using Grails 2.3.0 or later, you can do this like so:

```
class MyCommand {
    @BindingFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
    Date foo // bind this using a custom format, e.g. 'yyyy-MM-dd'
    Date bar // bind this using the normal 'struct' date picker fields
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write getter and setters that take the format you want and return the format you want. The DateFormatter or SimpleDateFormatter classes would be useful in your get/set methods.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Will that work with the idiomatic `myDomain.properties = params`, though? I have a feeling it won't. :(

Comment: I think that it will. Groovy calls the getters and setters for classes regardless of how you access the members.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the neat trick for dates in grails:

```
<g:form>
    <g:hiddenField name="myDomainInstance.bar_year" value="2011"/>
    <g:hiddenField name="myDomainInstance.bar_month" value="07"/>
    <g:hiddenField name="myDomainInstance.bar_day" value="01"/>
    <g:textField name="myDomainInstance.bar_hour" value=""/>
    <g:textField name="myDomainInstance.bar_minute" value=""/>
</g:form>
```

In controller:

```
myDomainInstance.properties = params.myDomainInstance
```

Will result in the desired date for `bar`.

Comment: I can, but I wouldn't really call that a "built-in" way; if I've got a field on a screen that accepts a "yyyy-MM-dd", I'd have to use javascript to parse it out into its hidden struct fields, which isn't very Grails-like.

Comment: this was just a solution for dates, which you do not want to be entered in one input field (as you have mentioned for `bar`).. for an input field which you want to be entered in one input field (like `foo`), you can use your property editor. sorry if this answer was redundant ;-)

Comment: I guess I'm not quite following what you're saying. If I'm binding a parameter map to a Date object on my command/domain, it's my understanding that a Custom Editor would apply to all such bindings, and therefore the `struct` binding wouldn't work. Is that not the case?

Comment: I suppose I can try it. :) I may experiment with it over lunch today.